# Sort elements of an Array in a Linq query?

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, linq, sorting

I have a `List(of Integer())` and I would like to sort the elements of the integer array, all this in-one-line, the problem is that the `Array.Sort` method does not return a value then which would be an efficient way?

So for example my list contains as the first Array element (**MyArrayList.First**) this Array:

```
{4, 5, 2, 6, 3, 1}
```

I need to sort the elements

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

Example (not working):

```
' Combos is the List(of Integer())
Combos = (From Combo As Integer() In Combos 
          Select Array.Sort(Combo)).ToList
```

Comment: Just use the `Sort` method of the `List<>` class: `Combos.Sort();`. It doesn't return anything because it sorts the list that you call it on.

Comment: @Guffa no, the Sort method of a List can't and will not reorder the list elements if they are an Array (at least without implementing a comparer in the method overload but I don't know how to write the proper comparer sorry). thanks for comment

Comment: Sorry, I missed the parentheses in the type that makes it a list of arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One line:

```
Dim result = (From item As Integer() In list Select (From n As Integer In item Select n Order By n Ascending).ToArray()).ToList()
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for

```
    Combos.ForEach(Sub(x As Integer()) Array.Sort(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Why the desire to use just one line?

```
For Each x In combos : Array.Sort(x) : Next
```